# Get only the Date portion of a date time column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the set portion of the below query how would I get it to grab just the date portion of the datetime column in MS SQL 2012?

```
update db.dbo.Prod

set
db.DBO.prod.code5 = l.datetime

FROM 
db.DBO.ali l

INNER JOIN
db.dbo.prod p

ON

l.part = p.KEYCODE and p.code5 = '' and L.PREFIX = 'D' AND l.part like 'ACD%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of `code5`?  If it is a date, then your code is fine.  If not, you can cast the value.

You should also be consistent in your use of aliases:

```
UPDATE p
    SET code5 = CAST(l.datetime as DATE)
FROM db.DBO.ali l INNER JOIN
     db.dbo.prod p
     ON l.part = p.KEYCODE and p.code5 = '' and L.PREFIX = 'D' AND l.part like 'ACD%'
```

Comment: It is varchar(50) and I can't change it unfortunately. The cast worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: If it's a varchar, then you're going to have an implicit cast that converts the date to a string. It's probably better to explicitly use CONVERT, and pass a string format so you can specify the format the date takes... otherwise you could get different strings based on the locale you're running in, which could cause some issues for some applications.